# Trying to open file but instead getting pointer location C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I am making a program that gets info about a Doom wad file.

Now, I have made the code to get the wad type (IWAD/PWAD) by checking the first byte. If it's `I`, it's an IWAD. If it's `P`, it's a PWAD.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum WadType
{
    iwad,
    pwad
};

class WadHeader
{
  public:
    WadType wadType;
    int lumpc;
    int dir;
    WadHeader(fstream& wadFile)
    {
        char x;
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int z;
        wadFile.read(&x, 1);
        if (x == 0x49) // "I" didn't work
        {
            wadType = iwad;
        }
        else if (x == 0x50) // "P" didn't work
        {
            wadType = pwad;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid wad byte: " << hex << showbase << static_cast<int>(x) << endl;
            throw runtime_error("not a valid wad");
        }
        wadFile.seekg(4);
        wadFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&y), 4);
        lumpc = y;
        wadFile.seekg(8);
        wadFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&z), 4);
        dir = z;
    }
};

class Wad
{
  public:
    Wad(string wn) : wadName(wn), headerInfo(wadFile)
    {
        wadFile.open(wn, ios::in |
                             ios::out |
                             ios::binary);
        if (!wadFile.is_open())
        {
            throw runtime_error("file not open");
        }
        cout << headerInfo.wadType << endl
             << headerInfo.lumpc << endl
             << headerInfo.dir;
    }
    ~Wad()
    {
        wadFile.close();
    }

  private:
    fstream wadFile;
    string wadName;
    WadHeader headerInfo;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Wad wad("GOLDTESTS.wad");
}
```

However, it is giving me random bytes. I think that it is reading the pointer location instead of the value.

I also have a different version of the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

enum WadType
{
    iwad,
    pwad
};

class WadHeader
{
  public:
    WadType wadType;
    int lumpc;
    int dir;

    WadHeader(fstream *wadFile)
    {
        unsigned char x;
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int z;
        x = wadFile->get();
        if (x == 0x49)
        {
            wadType = iwad;
        }
        else if (x == 0x50)
        {
            wadType = pwad;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid wad byte: " << hex << showbase << static_cast<int>(x) << endl;
            throw runtime_error("not a valid wad");
        }
        wadFile->seekg(4);
        wadFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&y), 4);
        lumpc = y;
        wadFile->seekg(8);
        wadFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&z), 4);
        dir = z;
    }
};

class Wad
{
  public:
    Wad(string wn) : wadName(wn), headerInfo(&wadFile)
    {
        wadFile.open(wn, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
        if (!wadFile.is_open())
        {
            throw runtime_error("file not open");
        }
        cout << headerInfo.wadType << endl
             << headerInfo.lumpc << endl
             << headerInfo.dir;
    }

    ~Wad()
    {
        wadFile.close();
    }

  private:
    fstream wadFile;
    WadHeader headerInfo;
    string wadName;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Wad wad("GOLDTESTS.wad");
    return 0;
}
```

This one instead just says the first byte is `0xFF`.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You'll want to be sure you're handling *endian* issues properly here. You also might want to use `uint32_t` to be specific, as well as `sizeof(uint32_t)` to be sure you're reading the right data, if not have a wrapper function `read(uint32_t& v)` or equivalent.

Comment: OT: But please try to avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `0x49` you mean the character `'I'` then write the character.

Comment: Also, the single first byte is simply not enough to make sure that the file is the correct format. You need to read and check the whole identifier.

Comment: And if the first "id" part of the header is four bytes, and you read one byte, how much should you seek to skip the remaining *three* bytes?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no, a WAD file starts with IWAD or PWAD, if the first byte isn't I or P, then, it is invalid

Comment: But there are ***many*** file-types which can begin with the byte representing `'I'` or `'P'`. How do you know that it's a `IWAD` or `PWAD` unless you actually read and check all four bytes? If the filename will be user-provided just reading the first byte isn't enough.

Comment: If `"I"` and `"P"` doesn't work, try `'I'` and `'P'`. If it still doesn't work, you are using a non-ASCII system.

Comment: The in initialization of `headerInfo` by `Wad(string wn) : wadName(wn), headerInfo(wadFile)` will happen before `wadFile` is opened in the body of the `Wad` constructor.

Comment: And I recommend you create a (packed) structure representing all bytes of the header, and read it all in one go. And *always* check that the read operation was successful (i.e. `if (!wadFile.read(...)) { /* error */ }`)

Comment: Err... could you be using `wadFile` to *initialize* `headerInfo` at ctor initialization time while it is only intialized in ctor body? Said differently, remove `, headerInfo(&wadFile)` from the ctor definition and add `headerInfo = WadHeader(&wadFile);` in the body, once `wadFile` has been initialized.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wads have a header composed of 4 bytes saying IWAD or PWAD, another 4 bytes saying the number of lumps, and another 4 pointing to the directory start location

Comment: Remember that `"P"` is a `char*` C string, a pointer, while `'P'` is a single character.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the first 4 bytes and compare that to the two possible strings.

Comment: Well the answer is below. My advice is to remove `wadFile` from `Wad`. An fstream is a object you use to read a file, it's not part of a file, so basic class design tells you that it should not a member of `Wad`. Instead open the file first, and then pass the `fstream` as a parameter to a reading function/method. This straightforward and sensible approach would have avoided your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor body of Wad runs after the constructor of WadHeader, but you open file in Wad() and read it in WadHeader(). So, you are trying to read from an unopened file.

To resolve it, you should rethink what's happening in Wad constructor, what in WadHeader constructor and when to open file (usually a constructor is not the place). An easy solution is to set the values to defaults or zeros in WarHeader constructor, and put the reading code in a method init(), read(), or similar.

Comment: Even easier: verify that each read succeeded by testing the stream state rather than assuming that the read was successful. Error conditions that you do not test for, trap, and handle generally become bugs.

Comment: thank you, i renamed the constructor to a method called wadRead and executed it after the file has been opened and it works!

Comment: @user4581301 how do i test for that?

Comment: @GoldenStar `if (!wadFile.read(...)) { some kind of error }`